# What is "making up one's life"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

> Having evaded wretchedness, the gay young man *making up his shining life* in the city is one of civilization’s wonders, and Édouard Louis is a new, inspiring real-life example of such transfiguration.

Comment: @mplungjan ... any definition that usefully starts at #63 (!!!) should probably be integrated into an answer here, rather than e.g. left as a close reason or even just a comment. (And tbh I somewhat doubt the applicability of that definition to this usage in modern English.)

Comment: @mplungjan I looked through #63--which has a ton of entries by the way--but still can't find an entry that seems to explain the sentence. The closest ones are #63(a) (b) (c), respectively: _(of parts) to constitute; compose; form.
to put together; construct; compile.
to concoct; invent._ These are meanings I am fairly familiar with. But I am not sure people say, for example, "put together his shining life".

Comment: @NathanTuggy - at the time I did not have time to answer. Please see my answer and comment if needed

Answer (score 1):

The construct is not common, but when [reading the article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/entertainment/books/the-end-of-eddy-marks-the-beginning-of-a-powerful-writers-career/2017/05/09/130ac0cc-34bf-11e7-b4ee-434b6d506b37_story.html?utm_term=.432969cdc32a) and taking the list of explanations of [make](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/making-up) (63.) at dictionary.com I believe the author of the article is using "making up" in the sense of

- construct
- reconcile

Making something of his life after a long period of strife...

The article author, who is also gay, may also have made a pun on "make up" that the young man ultimately improved and polished his life.

> 63.
>   **make up,**
>
> - to put together; construct; compile.
> -   -
> - Also, make up for. to compensate for; make good.
> -   -
> - to complete.
> - -
> - to put in order; arrange:
> - -
> - to conclude; decide.
> - to settle amicably, as differences.
> - to become reconciled, as after a quarrel.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiom "Make it up as you go", which means "improvise continuously".  The quoted phrase can be interpreted to mean he is constructing a new life without a plan for what it will be in the end.